# Game UI Position Change on build while works fine in unity editor with same resolution

Tags: c#, user-interface, unity-game-engine, build

the ui of my game works fine and are positioned correctly in my unity editor but the position of ui elements changes when i build and play the game in my android. the resolution of my phone and the unity editor is completely same which is 2257 X 1080. and the place of only a few ui elements changes. i don't know how to add images here so i just have this question here.
[this is incorrect in android phone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xQxBH.jpg)

[This is the correct seen in editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WHwmV.jpg)

[Canvas Inspector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TW6HU.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

Set the anchors of your ui(images, buttons) to the nearest position(center, left...etc) they can be.

Comment: But why the position of ui is correct in editor and wrong in android build?

Answer (score 0):

First things first you can add the images by clicking the image icon when posting you question/answer on stack-overflow.

Now to answer your question, you need to set your canvas `UI Scale Mode` to `Scale With Screen Size`. Also set the appropriate anchors for each object.

This is what I could tell by reading your question if this does not solve the issue then add more details to your question.

Comment: @thirteen4053, done and yes i have already my anchors and canvas to that.

Comment: can you also add screen shot of `canvas` `inspector`

Comment: ,,, canvas inspecter added

Comment: Yes that everything seems to be in order. What are the anchor points for both your menus? They should be top right and bottom right.